# Saving records in a protected folder .htaccess, secure?

Tags: .htaccess, security

I have done quite a lot of searching but am not really able to find a clear answer. I'm wondering if storing simple generated record documents (`.txt` files, e.g. purchase records) in a protected directory with `deny from all` is secure? Obviously, anyone going directly to the file in the browser will not be able to access it, but I wonder if the information in these text files is visible in other ways?

Comment: This is kind of secure, _if you do not implement holes into your setup_ which is something we cannot say and you cannot say for sure. That is a general issue without a general solution. Best always is to save such resources _outside_ the section of the file system accessible to the http server, _if your setup allows for that_ ...

Comment: I am using a hosting service, so I believe I don't have access outside the public html file system ... :(

Comment: Could be, but then again: isn't the ``public_html`` folder just exactly that, a folder inside the part of the file system you have to access to? So why can't you define a folder side by side to that?

Answer (score -2):

Why store them in a place accessible by the browser? Can’t you place the files somewhere else in the server, in a directory that is not seen by the http server?
I assume you would like to access them later through the browser and if that’s the case, can’t you create those reports on the fly each time a request is made for them? I have seen servers littered with saved reports when the best solution would have been to generate the reports again by retrieving data from a database. Please do not take this as an insult, but if my assumption is correct, try to consider another solution.
Technically, the answer to your question is “those files are not accessible if the server is configured correctly, you have no bugs in the code, etc.”

Comment: My preference would be to store these files underneath the root, however I am using a somewhat basic hosting service and believe I don't have access to any folders beneath the root. In this case, would it be worth contacting the provider? I've had little experience with this kind of situation until now. In terms of usability I don't mind the .htaccess version since I can get the records through my ftp program, but the security question is something that keeps coming to mind since the record has email addresses, etc.

Comment: @ThomasNicholson "files underneath the root" / "any folders beneath the root" - more commonly referred to as being **above** the root.